# Electron store data locally without localstorage

Tags: javascript, php, json, electron, local-storage

I have an [Electron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_(software_framework)) application built using *JavaScript*.

I need to store some data and still retain it after closing the application.

I have find many ways, like JSON and localstorage.

I can't edit JSON using JavaScript only. I need a server, but my application is local, I have many computers, and I can't host a localserver for each version of the application.

I found `localstorage`, but when I change the destination of the application, it deletes all data and it's a danger. Any problem in Electron and all data is deleted.

So I need to store data in Electron locally and *read/write* data using JavaScript.

I think with server-side. I can read/write, but I need a localhost, and my Electron application is just a client-side program, like a browser.

All my solutions have a problem. I need a database *read/write* client side and not localstorage.

I searched on the Internet along, but I couldn’t found anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently there is no built-in way to do this apart from using localstorage.

If it is okay for you to use a third-party module and save your data in an unencrypted JSON file, you could use [the electron-store module](https://github.com/sindresorhus/electron-store).

According to their documentation there is a simple [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) API.
This is an example from their GitHub README file:

```js
const Store = require('electron-store');

const store = new Store();

store.set('unicorn', '');
console.log(store.get('unicorn'));
//=> ''

// Use dot-notation to access nested properties
store.set('foo.bar', true);
console.log(store.get('foo'));
//=> {bar: true}

store.delete('unicorn');
console.log(store.get('unicorn'));
//=> undefined
```